# http4s-ember-server throws ClosedChannelException from time to time

Tags: scala, scala-cats, http4s

Using http4s-ember-server on one of my applications I notice from time to time these exceptions appearing in my server's logs.

What is odd about them is that they don't follow my logger's appender or formatting style, they are just plain text like this, these stack lines go in separate lines so my kubernetes receives them as separate log messages while my normal exceptions and any application logs are formatted into a JSON, even exceptions are nicely in one block. So this must be coming from something low level.

I also noticed, only 1 of my 3 very similar applications throws these, so it can't be the meta/health, ready or buildinfo endpoints.

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.begin(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:118)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.shutdownInput(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:536)
    at fs2.io.net.SocketCompanionPlatform$AsyncSocket.$anonfun$readChunk$3(SocketPlatform.scala:121)
    at delay @ fs2.io.net.SocketCompanionPlatform$AsyncSocket.$anonfun$readChunk$2(SocketPlatform.scala:120)
    at delay @ fs2.io.net.SocketCompanionPlatform$AsyncSocket.$anonfun$readChunk$1(SocketPlatform.scala:120)
    at async @ fs2.io.net.SocketCompanionPlatform$AsyncSocket.readChunk(SocketPlatform.scala:114)
    at flatMap @ fs2.io.net.SocketCompanionPlatform$BufferedReads.$anonfun$read$1(SocketPlatform.scala:82)
    at delay @ fs2.io.net.SocketCompanionPlatform$BufferedReads.withReadBuffer(SocketPlatform.scala:52)
    at flatten$extension @ org.http4s.ember.server.internal.Shutdown$$anon$1.<init>(Shutdown.scala:71)
    at onError @ com.c1999.n1999.w1999.NWApp$.run(NWApp.scala:15) <- this is the only line that states my own code
    at getAndSet @ org.typelevel.keypool.KeyPool$.destroy(KeyPool.scala:120)
```

Has anyone encountered such exceptions with http4s servers?

The source code around line 15 looks like

```scala
val program =
      (for {
        twoConfigs <- NWAppConfig
          .load[IO]        
          .onError(error => logger.error(error)(show"failed to load config with: $error")) // line 15 here
          .toResource
        (appConfig, requestContextConfig) = twoConfigs
        components <- NWComponents(appConfig, requestContextConfig)
        _ <- logger.info("started").toResource
        _ <- components.streamsJoined.compile.drain
          .onError(error => logger.error(error)(s"error in nw: $error"))
          .toResource
      } yield ()).use_
```

Comment: What version of http4s, CE, and fs2? I think there was a mild bug around resource handling where this can happen

Comment: cats-core:2.9.0, cats-effect:3.5.1, http4s-ember-server:0.23.23, com.softwaremill.sttp.client3:fs2:3.8.13,fs2-core:3.7.0 . I don't know, we keep everything up to date the newest newest. Except we haven't gone 1.+ with http4s, as it is "non-production warranted" yet.

Comment: yeah as of right now continue with 0.23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this same issue today and it took me a while to track down... What's happening here is that the finaliser is throwing a (benign) exception, which is being printed directly to the console via `def reportFailure` in the IOApp you're using to evaluate your program. This can be redirected to your preferred logging library by overriding the implementation - if you're in an IOApp, it's as simple as

```
override protected def reportFailure(err: Throwable): IO[Unit] = myLogImpl(err)
```

or if you're evaluating with an `unsafeFoo` method, instead of using IORuntime.global, you can construct your own IORuntime with `val myRuntime = IORuntimeBuilder.apply().setFailureReporter(t => myLogImpl(t)).build()` and pass it to the unsafe method with e.g `.unsafeRunSync()(myRuntime)`

Comment: I’ll try and i’ll come back with my findings. Thank you!

Comment: Yes it worked. Now at least the stacktrace is in one log entry, it's according to my log formatting. The error does not disappear but at least it can be hidden/down-leveled by log level, etc. I'm still curious though when will ember-server fix this. Thank you @user2738017

Comment: After upgrading to `http4s-ember-server:0.23.24` I started to see the entire `ClosedChannelException` disappearing. Let's see if this trend keeps on.